# Problem with importing GeoTif files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, mac, osx

I have installed the new version of QGIS (2.12) and the newest OSX version (El Capitan).
When I tried to open GeoTif files with QGIS, it always crashed!
Then I tried an older version of QGIS (2.8) and the same problem appeared!
I don´t know what to do know and I hope there is anybody who is good with QGIS and MAC!

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using, KyngChaos, Homebrew, MacPorts or ...

Comment: Here is the link of the page I´ve downloaded it: http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis.                                                  So it seems to be the version QGIS 2.12.0-1. My macbook has the version Mac OSX 10.11.1 installed.

Comment: [Install Qgis On mac Os X El Capitan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1yqT0wgHqs)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I´ve already done that all before and qgis also runs already on my mac! My only problem is, that I can´t open GeoTif files without crashing QGIS! When I start a project without GeoTif files, it works as it should!

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with the package installed following the Kyngchaos website. I installed GIS 2.8 via Homebrew following [this tutorial](http://justinzimmerman.net/installing-postgis-and-qgis-using-homebrew/) and now I'm able to import GeoTiff files.

Summary of the installation process:

```
brew install postgresql
brew install python  
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH  
pip install numpy scipy matplotlib processing psycopg2
brew install gdal 
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac  
brew install qgis-28  
brew linkapps qgis-28
```

Comment: Did anyone find out what the problem was? and is it fixed? I am having similar trouble with QGIS 2.16.4. I have tried on 2.8.2 and still crashing. I am trying to open 1gb tiff files from Sentinel 1 on a Windows 7 64bit machine. Reinstalling on my work machine is not an option.

Comment: I was experiencing this problem on 2.14. When I updated to 2.16 using the King Chaos build today I no longer had this problem.